# Python3 TypeError: sequence item 9: expected str instance, tuple found

Tags: python

I'm trying to get stats, but it suddenly started failing with "TypeError: sequence item 9: expected str instance, tuple found" error.

Code is:

```
try:
    message.reply_text(
        "Maintained by [Dank-del](t.me/dank_as_fuck) and [Eclipsa](tg://user?id=1659080755)\n"
        f"Built with ❤️ using python-telegram-bot\n\n{status}"
        "\n*Bot statistics*:\n\n".join([mod.__stats__() for mod in STATS])
        + "\n\n*SRC*: [GitHub](https://github.com/Eclipswf/Caelum)",
    parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN, disable_web_page_preview=True)
except BaseException:
    message.reply_text(
        "Maintained by [Dank-del](t.me/dank_as_fuck) and [Eclipsa](tg://user?id=1659080755)\n"
        "Built with ❤️ using python-telegram-bot\n"
        "\n*Bot statistics*:\n\n".join([mod.__stats__() for mod in STATS])
        + "\n\n*SRC*: [GitHub](https://github.com/Eclipswf/Caelum)",
    parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN, disable_web_page_preview=True)
```

and the error I get: https://nekobin.com/hokecabiho.py

also source code: https://github.com/Eclipswf/Caelum

Comment: Please add the code as a text not as a link

Comment: nekobin or github link? if not any of them can you tell how? I'm new here sorry

Comment: Just copy paste the code here in the question between ```    code   ```

Comment: Okay done I guess

Answer (score 0):

Use `str(mod.__stats__())` instead of `mod.__stats__()`, one of the elements is a tuple, which can not be automatically `join`ed because it is not a `str`ing.

Comment: @MehmetKan I dont't know what I'm supposed to do with that ... Can you explain what you mean ?

Comment: Bot copied `status = ""` message 9 times as STATS have 9 things like:
```• System Start time: 2021-06-16 23:06:22
'• 0 overall warns, across 0 chats.
• System Start time: 2021-06-16 23:06:22
• 0 chats have rules set
• System Start time: 2021-06-16 23:06:22
• 0 disabled items, across 0 chats.```
This made the message even longer cause it has more system info